# Duration in minutes seconds and miliseconds

Tags: java

In Java 8 I would like to display the duration as minutes, seconds and miliseconds. How do I compute the remaining miliseconds?

```
duration = Duration.between(startLocalDateTime, endLocalDateTime).toMillis();

System.out.println("migration lasted " + String.format("%d minutes %d seconds", 
  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration) - 
  TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration))
  
  ));
```

Comment: What's your Java version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `java.time`, that means there's no need to compute the remaining milliseconds because a `Duration` has methods to output them since Java 9:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // some example LocalDateTimes for a Duration
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    LocalDateTime someTimeBeforeNow = now.minusHours(1)
                                         .minusMinutes(2)
                                         .minusSeconds(12)
                                         .minusNanos(2000000);
    // create the Duration
    Duration duration = Duration.between(someTimeBeforeNow, now);
    // print the unit parts
    System.out.println(String.format("Duration: %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds, %d milliseconds",
                        duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutesPart(),
                        duration.toSecondsPart(), duration.toMillisPart()));
}
```

will print

```
Duration: 1 hours, 2 minutes, 12 seconds, 2 milliseconds
```

If you are on Java 8, then take the methods that give you the full duration in the desired unit and divide correspondigly.

Change the output of the example above to

```java
System.out.println(String.format("Duration: %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds, %d milliseconds",
                    duration.toHours(), duration.toMinutes() % 60,
                    duration.toSeconds() % 60, duration.toMillis() % 1000));
```

Comment: Remove the `Part` from `toHours`, in case the duration is longer than one day.

Comment: I am running Java 8.

Comment: @AnaSustic OK, I added a Java 8 version.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 9+, you use the `xxxPart()` methods:

```java
Duration duration = Duration.ofMillis(12345678);

System.out.printf("%d minutes %d seconds %d milliseconds%n",
                  duration.toMinutes(),
                  duration.toSecondsPart(),
                  duration.toMillisPart());
```

*Output*

```
205 minutes 45 seconds 678 milliseconds
```

Note how the minutes is not a `xxxPart()` method, since we want the overflow into hours, as extra minutes.